# Spring Data Hibernate Cascade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i've some problems related to hibernates cascading operations within the usage of Spring Data.
At first my entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne {

    @Id
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private EntityTwo entityTwo;

}


@Entity
public class EntityTwo {

    @Id
    private String code;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityTwo")
    private Set<EntityOne> entitiesOne;
}
```

I've wrote an EntityImport based on Spring Batch with uses a Processer which checks via the `Repository.findOne(example)` if there is already an existing entity (and do some deep property merging) and a `RepositoryItemWriter` to write the "created" Entities into the database.

And now my Problem: If there are no existing ParentData in the database, everything works fine. The Import creates an `EntityOne` with a linked `EntityTwo`. After using saving both Entities are persisted in the Database.
But when i try to repeat this process, i get a `DataIntegrityViolationException`

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [EntityTwo#EntityTwoCode]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1735)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:524)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(SimpleJpaRepository.java:425)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
```

The weird thing is, that i dont get this at the `Repository.save(EntityOne)` call but previous to this on a `Repository.findOne(example.of(EntityOne))` call which results in a autoflush by hibernate resulting in the exception above.

Comment: Please post the code from your repository.

Comment: i use the standard JpaRepository, no custom code there